# Can I wait to take my GRE until after my bachelors, thus delaying my application dates for graduate school

Tags: gre

I'm panicking quite a bit at the moment. I realized far too late that I need to be applying to graduate school yesterday. The problem is I'm completely broke. I have 1000 dollars to my name and I need for gas it to commute to school.

I'm a theoretical mathematics major, chemistry minor, and I'm also worried about my performance. I can handle as much Abstract Algebra, Linear Algebra, Combinatorics, an the like as they want to throw at me but taking limits and manual integration and the more elementary things have not been in my life for a long time. Also I haven't yet completed/taken the full analysis series or topology yet.

I have a lot of questions, I also don't know where to expect to be accepted. I've got decent grades, I have to calculate some stuff but I think I
m sitting above a 3.7. I have kids and cant travel far (I already commute 75 miles) And what to do if I don't get in anywhere. I LOVE mathematics, I love learning, but did I just waste 80,000 dollars and 5 years of my life because I couldn't be better. I'm more competent than most of my classmates 99% of the time (I'm taking two graduate level classes this semester so it's a bit different), I feel like I have something special to offer.....

Anyways I'm rambling, I'll save those questions for other threads, I could spend my gas money and hope it works out in the end, but I think I may do very poorly. I'm looking for a job. What should I do?

Comment: Hi Ronnie, I'm sympathetic to your issue because I did precisely this (and am currently in between undergraduate and graduate studies!) In fact, I am also a math major. One productive (I hope!) option is to opt for  a post-bacc program. See https://pages.wustl.edu/jointpostbac, https://orion.math.iastate.edu/lidicky/postbac/ are two such *math-specific* programs that are funded. Note also that there are fee waivers available for the GRE's at your undergraduate institution, although it might be hard (possibly impossible) to get them this soon ebfore the test.

Comment: Anyway, don't freak out, plenty of undergraduates do this. However, it would be good to apply for academic-related things for now, or see if undergrad professors might be willing to supervise a research project etc... I am also quite bad at the GRE, I'll let you know how that goes for me :). You can also use the year to learn some topology/analysis, which would surely benefit you. Best of luck, and hopefully some professors will chime in! P.S Stonybrook University which has a really nice program doesn't require the GRE.

Comment: My apologies for not asking a more general question, I suppose this site is intended for questions that would help others. Thank you for the replies, I will have too wait but if I can get a fee waiver I will take the general.

Answer (score 2):

You can only do what you can do. The timing of your future education is less important (my view) than that you make a plan to get there.

Make a list of your options. For each option list its advantages and disadvantages. Prioritize them. Don't neglect your family's needs in the list of priorities.

Choose one that has a reasonable path and chance of success. It needn't be the optimal solution. It needs to be a workable solution.